# Is there a way for screen reader to speak a label and the contents of an element as well?

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

Let's say I have the following HTML

```
<div class="address">
    171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002
</div>
```

The address value is dynamically populated by the application. 
Visually, the user understands that this is an address given the context of the page. Meaning: there is no need to add the word "ADDRESS" in the `innerText`.

However, If the user is using a screen reader, then once the elements gets focused, it will speak the contents `171 E Broadway, New......`.

If I apply the `aria-label="address"`, then the screen reader will just say `address` and will not prononuce the content of the html element.

I tried adding `aria-labeledby`

```
<span id="address-label" hidden>Address</span>

<div class="address" aria-labeledby="address-label">
    171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002
</div>
```

But the screen reader says "ADDRESS". Does not speak the content of the address.

Then I tried `aria-describedby`

```
<span id="address-label" hidden>Address</span>

<div class="address" aria-describedby="address-label">
    171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002
</div>
```

That works, but it speaks the entire address content, then appends the word "ADDRESS" at the end.

Is there a way to make the screen reader say `"ADDRESS: 171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002"` without visually adding the word "ADDRESS" on the page?

Answer (score 1):

This is redundant, but would provide the result that you want. I'm not aware of a more elegant solution.

```
<span id="address-label" hidden>Address: 171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002</span>

<div class="address" aria-labeledby="address-label">
    171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002
</div>
```